# How can I find which JNI library implements a java native method at runtime for Android applications?

Tags: android, java

I am doing security research, my target application includes some JNI libraries which implements some native java methods I am interested in. This app is obfuscated, I can't directly find the library by unpacking the APK archive.

Searching on the Web I found I can use ART's [GetNativeMethods()](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/refs/heads/main:art/runtime/native_bridge_art_interface.cc;drc=e759826803f67ead26354fbcaf746ec6d74e178f;l=56) from a JNI function, then use the native method's JNI pointer to find the shared library where it is located. But ART is a private API and latest Android versions block the loading of `libart.so`, I can't use it.

I am using Xposed to instrument the target application at runtime.

Comment: I know only two way to access a native method via JNI: 1. the method is exported by the library 2. using the JNI method `RegisterNatives` https://www.baeldung.com/jni-registernatives

Comment: @Robert so I should somehow hook into RegisterNatives to find the native methods name mapping? Yes I guess they use that to be able to obfuscated the symbols in the JNI library.

Comment: Yes, but finding this method isn't that easy. As you can see on the linked web site `RegisterNatives` is not an exported method but a method that belongs to a struct. So you first have to find the struct then calculate the offset to the method pointer in the struct to get the final pointer you can hook.